# Create a google Script for finding and replacing text in the same cell on each page of a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have 2 variables that I need to update on several hundred pages of a spreadsheet. But I only need it changed in cell B1 for each page and not any other cells. If B1 is Apple I need it to say Red Apple and if B1 is Banana I need it to say Yellow Banana.

```
function run() {
runReplaceInSheet();
replaceInSheet();
}

function runReplaceInSheet() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); 
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for ( var i = 0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
var sheet = sheets[i];
// Fetch the range of cells 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1) // Numbers of rows to process
// Fetch values for each row in the Range
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

// Replace Names

replaceInSheet(values, 'Apple', 'Red Apple');

//write the updated values to the sheet, again less call;less overhead
sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);        

}
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {

//loop over the rows in the array
for (var row in values) {

//use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
    return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace, replace_with);
});

//replace the original row values with the replaced values
values[row] = replaced_values;


}
}
```

Here is the updated code I tried to use that keeps timing out.

```
function run() {
runReplaceInSheet();
replaceInSheet();
}

function runReplaceInSheet() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]); 
var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
var numRows = 1; //  number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1) // Numbers of rows to process
// Fetch values for each row in the Range
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var value = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();  

// Replace Names

replaceInSheet(values, 'Apple', 'Red Apple');

//write the updated values to the sheet, again less call;less overhead
sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(value);         

}
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {

//loop over the rows in the array
for (var row in values) {

//use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
    return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace, replace_with);
});

//replace the original row values with the replaced values
values[row] = replaced_values;


}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried.

Comment: I copied some script I had found on Stackoverflow and tried to modify it. But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

For every sheet in the spreadsheet the code in the question grabs all the values but you only need to replace the value of a single cell.

Also, the replace function do the replace in all the cells.

To grab the value of B1 instead of

```
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

use

```
var value = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
```

then you could use compare the value to see if the replace is necesary, and if so, instead of

```
sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
```

you might use

```
sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(value);
```

Comment: I get the following Error
We're sorry, a server error occurred. 
Please wait a bit and try again.
runReplaceInSheet @ Find and Replace.gs:8
run @ Find and Replace.gs:2

Comment: @ToddCash As the error says, wait a bit and try again.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will wait and see if it corrects.

Comment: Still not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ToddCash post a new question including the new code.

Comment: I added the updated code. Thanks for your help.